# Force Hoisting Of Package Dependencies In Yarn (v1) Workspace

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo, hoist

I have a monorepo containing many packages. It is using yarn(v1) workspaces. One of the packages contains a set of development dependencies (`packages/example-dev`/`@example/dev`) that are consumed as a package by applications external to the monorepo. I would also like these dependencies to be available to the monorepo root. However, they are not hoisted (presumably because they are not shared with any other packages).

**Is there any way to force the hoisting of packages in the `package.json` of my `@example/dev` to the workspace root?**

Note that I don't want to redeclare all the dev dependencies in the root.

Comment: Not quite sure it is possible but maybe a different approach would be to inherit common package.json snippets.
There is a nice tool for that: https://github.com/microsoft/package-inherit